# Unable to refer vijava jar file in Virgo Server

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, vmware, eclipse-virgo

I am trying to access java service project from Flex UI project. In Java service project, i am able to import "Vijava" jar file and its packages.. And it build successfully,, But When I add that into "Virgo" server, i am getting error as "Unresolved import package". Anyone have idea about this?

My error message is,

[2015-01-12 18:59:14.330] [INFO ] TCP Connection(15)-127.0.0.1   Installing bundle 'com.acme.selvaService.SelvaService' version '1.0.0'. 
[2015-01-12 18:59:14.400] [INFO ] TCP Connection(15)-127.0.0.1   Dump 'C:\ProgramData\vmware\vSphere Web Client\serviceability\dump\2015-01-12-18-59-385' generated 
[2015-01-12 18:59:14.449] [ERROR] TCP Connection(15)-127.0.0.1   Installation of bundle 'com.acme.selvaService.SelvaService' version '1.0.0' failed. org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.UnableToSatisfyBundleDependenciesException: Unable to satisfy dependencies of bundle 'com.acme.selvaService.SelvaService' at version '1.0.0': Cannot resolve: com.acme.selvaService.SelvaService
    Resolver report:
        An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data . Caused by missing constraint in bundle 
             constraint:

```
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.resolve.internal.QuasiResolveStage.process(QuasiResolveStage.java:46)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.CompensatingPipeline.doProcessGraph(CompensatingPipeline.java:73)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.driveInstallPipeline(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:359)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.doInstall(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:185)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.install(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:140)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.deploy(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:253)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.management.StandardDeployer.deploy(StandardDeployer.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor100.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:193)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:175)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:117)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:54)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[2015-01-12 18:59:14.463] [ERROR] TCP Connection(15)-127.0.0.1   Install failed for bundle 'com.acme.selvaService.SelvaService' version '1.0.0'. 
[2015-01-12 18:59:14.468] [ERROR] TCP Connection(15)-127.0.0.1   Unable to install application from URI 'file:/C:/sdk/vSphereWebClient/server/stage/SelvaService.jar'. Cannot satisfy constraints for bundle 'com.acme.selvaService.SelvaService' version '1.0.0'. Cannot resolve: com.acme.selvaService.SelvaService
    Resolver report:
        An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data . Caused by missing constraint in bundle 
             constraint: 
. org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.UnableToSatisfyBundleDependenciesException: Unable to satisfy dependencies of bundle 'com.acme.selvaService.SelvaService' at version '1.0.0': Cannot resolve: com.acme.selvaService.SelvaService
    Resolver report:
        An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data . Caused by missing constraint in bundle 
             constraint:

```
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.resolve.internal.QuasiResolveStage.process(QuasiResolveStage.java:46)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.CompensatingPipeline.doProcessGraph(CompensatingPipeline.java:73)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.driveInstallPipeline(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:359)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.doInstall(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:185)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.install(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:140)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.deploy(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:253)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.management.StandardDeployer.deploy(StandardDeployer.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor100.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:193)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:175)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:117)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:54)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[2015-01-12 18:59:14.488] [INFO ] TCP Connection(15)-127.0.0.1   Dump 'C:\ProgramData\vmware\vSphere Web Client\serviceability\dump\2015-01-12-18-59-487' generated

Comment: Did you check if a bundle exports the required package? You can use the Virgo Shell Command to list the bundles that export a class or package: [clexport command](http://eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.6.3.RELEASE/docs/virgo-user-guide/html/ch08s03.html#admin-shell-cl-clexport)

Comment: We verified that, all the required packages are included. Only the manifest data are missing in vijava and its dependent jar(eg: dom4j). We traced that, virgo server deployment requires this manifest information for "ALL" the dependent jars. But we are unable to proceed as none of the jars in the web vijava contain proper manifest.

Comment: You could try to wrap those jars: [Bnd / Wrapping](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Wrapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to wrap the required libraries as mentioned in the [vmware community forum](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/426877):

```
java -jar bnd-2.2.0.jar wrap -o dom4j-1.6.1.jar ../dom4j-1.6.1.jar
java -jar bnd-2.2.0.jar wrap -o vijava-55.jar vijava55b20130927.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It worked for dom4j-1.6.1.jar. But still i am facing same problem with vijava jar. To resolve that, I downloaded source code for vijava and imported that into one "Bundle Project". And removed the samples package from that source code. And then Right click on project Virgo->Run Generation of Manifest file. It will generate manifest information.

And with Remaining packages, I exported that project as new "jar" file with Manifest information. Now I put these jar file in server repository tried. It works..

But I still wonder why your vijava wrapper didnt work????

Comment: What command line did you use to wrap the vijava library? Could you post the generated `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` ?

Comment: I executed following command..

    java -jar bnd-2.2.0.jar wrap -o vijava-55.jar vijava55b20130927.jar
Warnings
000: Using defaults for wrap, which means no export versions

Comment: I couldnt add my manifest information in comment.. So i posted that as "Answer" please check that..

Comment: Looks good to me. Could you also post the ImportPackage from bundle com.acme.selvaService.SelvaService which is not resolved?

Comment: Sorry Florian Waibel... Actually i couldnt solve yet.. I just going with the "Work Around" with source code of Vijava..

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MyService
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.acme.myService.MyService
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Vendor: VMware
Import-Package: com.vmware.vim25.mo
Export-Package: com.acme.myService   

This is my Java Service project's Manifest information. Please look at it..

Answer (score 0):

```
Manifest information is 

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1421825261657
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: bin
Bundle-SymbolicName: bin
Bundle-Version: 0
Created-By: 1.7.0_71 (Oracle Corporation)

Export-Package: License.txt,README.txt,com.vmware.vim.cf;uses:="com.vmwa
 re.vim25,com.vmware.vim25.mo",com.vmware.vim.rest;uses:="javax.xml.xpat
 h",com.vmware.vim25;uses:="com.vmware.vim25.ws",com.vmware.vim25.mo;use
 s:="com.vmware.vim25",com.vmware.vim25.mo.util;uses:="com.vmware.vim25,
 com.vmware.vim25.mo",com.vmware.vim25.mox;uses:="com.vmware.vim25,com.v
 mware.vim25.mo",com.vmware.vim25.ws;uses:="com.vmware.vim25,org.dom4j",
 org.doublecloud.ws.util,rel-note.txt

Import-Package: javax.net.ssl;resolution:=optional,javax.xml.bind;resolu
 tion:=optional,javax.xml.xpath;resolution:=optional,org.dom4j;resolutio
 n:=optional,org.dom4j.io;resolution:=optional,org.xml.sax;resolution:=o
 ptional
Tool: Bnd-2.2.0.20130927-173453
```